# how Display the names of employees who are not working as managers?

Tags: sql

i need to retrieve all employees who are not working as managers

i tried with this code >

```
SELECT  MGR.LAST_NAME ,
    E.EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM    EMPLOYEES E , (SELECT  M.LAST_NAME ,
                           M.EMPLOYEE_ID 
                   FROM    EMPLOYEES E , EMPLOYEES M
                   WHERE   E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMPLOYEE_ID) MGR
WHERE   E.EMPLOYEE_ID = MGR.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: It seems that you *are* selecting the employees who are managers...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 E.LAST_NAME,
 E.EMPLOYEE_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES E
 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID not in 
       (SELECT MANAGER_ID FROM EMPLOYEES where MANAGER_ID is not null)
```

Comment: @AhmedRashad Glad to hear it, no problem!